# Why don't C++ class functions don't have low_pc / high_pc DWARF info

Tags: c++, debugging, dwarf

I'm trying to find the offset range of a c++ class function but when I look in the DWARF information, I don't see the low_pc or high_pc attributes. There are also no `DW_AT_specification` or `DW_AT_abstract_origin` entries for the DIE that has the rest of the function information. For example I can only see:

```
0x03989358:     DW_TAG_subprogram
                  DW_AT_decl_line       (539)
                  DW_AT_decl_file       ("file.h")
                  DW_AT_declaration     (0x01)
                  DW_AT_MIPS_linkage_name       ("Mangled function Class:Function")
                  DW_AT_accessibility   (DW_ACCESS_public)
                  DW_AT_name    ("Function")
```

And no other DIEs point to `0x03989358`

How can I obtain the offset range for these functions / why are they not included?

P.S. I got this info from dwarfdump and this is DWARFv3

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there might be more than one `DW_TAG_subprogram` element for a function in the same CU. The first one would have the function declaration, the second one would have the low_pc/high_pc, and a `DW_AT_specification` pointing at the first one.

Search the CU for `DW_TAG_subprogram` elements with low_pc/high_pc, see where it takes you.

Use [DWARF Explorer](https://pypi.org/project/dwex/) to eyeball the whole DIE tree, see if it helps.